# virtual function declared non-virtual in a derived class

Tags: c++

If a function is declared non-virtual in a derived class when the base class function was virutal, why does it invoke a vtable lookup on calling the function on its pointer? The function is clear from the scope.

Answer (score 21):

In C++ if you declare a method `virtual` in the base class then it's virtual also in derived class, even if the `virtual` keyword is omitted.

For documentation purposes is however in my opinion nice to repeat it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot make a function non-virtual, so it will stay virtual and a call to the function is in general also virtual. Of course, there are situations where the compiler will be able to optimize this and do a direct call, but apparantly not in your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The function is still virtual (assuming it has the same or a covariant signature). Using `virtual` when overriding is redundant.

Comment: It may be redundant to the compiler but it is good documentation for any human using the class.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual methods created to affect on derived class *(When you mark a method as virtual. It will use vtable on derived classes)*. And the overrided methods will be virtual.

Answer (score 0):

When a class inherits a virtual function, any new, overriding declaration of that function will automatically be made virtual, even if the `virtual` keyword is not used.